# In ASP.NET MVC C# database First I am doing sum of values in textboxes but in database it does not insert the SUM result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to find sum of values in textboxes and then display the SUM in another textbox and also STORE THE SUM IN DATABASE .
Using the code below it succesfully find sum and display it in another textbox However it does not store the sum in database.

I checked the database, it shows the value NULL is entered in TotalAvgHours field of database.

```
[HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public ActionResult Create(TimePeriodViewModel timePeriodVM)
            {
                var timeperiod = new TimePeriod
                {
                 
                    TotalAvgHours = timePeriodVM.TimePeriod.TotalAvgHours,
                    
    }
```

View

Total

```
            <td>
        @Html.TextBox("TotalAvgHours", "", "{0:c}", new { disabled = "disabled", @class = "form-control", id = "res2" })
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function sum2() {
                var one = document.getElementById('a2').value || "0";
                var two = document.getElementById('b2').value || "0";
                var three = document.getElementById('c2').value || "0";
                var four = document.getElementById('d2').value || "0";
                var five = document.getElementById('e2').value || "0";
                var six = document.getElementById('f2').value || "0";
                var seven = document.getElementById('g2').value || "0";
                var eight = document.getElementById('h2').value || "0";
                var nine = document.getElementById('i2').value || "0";
                var ten = document.getElementById('j2').value || "0";
                var eleven = document.getElementById('k2').value || "0";
                var twelve = document.getElementById('l2').value || "0";
                var thirteen = document.getElementById('m2').value || "0";
                var fourteen = document.getElementById('n2').value || "0";
                var fifteen = document.getElementById('o2').value || "0";

                var result = parseFloat(one) + parseFloat(two) + parseFloat(three) + parseFloat(four) + parseFloat(five) + parseFloat(six) + parseFloat(seven) +
                    parseFloat(eight) + parseFloat(nine) + parseFloat(ten) + parseFloat(eleven) + parseFloat(twelve) + parseFloat(thirteen) + parseFloat(fourteen) + parseFloat(fifteen);
                if (!isNaN(result)) {
                    document.getElementById('res2').value = result;
                }
            }
            window.onload = sum2;

        </script>
    </td>
    
    
</tr>
```

TimePeriodViewModel

```
 public class TimePeriodViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Personnel> Personnels { get; set; }
       //public Personnel Personnel { get; set; }
       public int PersonnelID { get; set; }
       
        public IEnumerable<DailyRegister> DailyRegisters { get; set; }
        public DailyRegister DailyRegister { get; set; }
        public TimePeriod TimePeriod { get; set; }

    }
```

TimePeriod

```
 public partial class TimePeriod
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public TimePeriod()
        {
            this.DailyRegisters = new HashSet<DailyRegister>();
        }
    
        public int TimePeriodID { get; set; }
        public int PersonnelID { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsSignedAvgAgreement { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsSignedTimeSheet { get; set; }
        public string SignedAvgBy { get; set; }
        public string SignedTimeSheetBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> SignedTimeSheetDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> TotalAvgHours { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> TotalTimeSheetHours { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> TotalOvertime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug the request? We are not seeing any `dbContext` operation the code you shared so far? Did you shared the full code? In addition please share `TimePeriodViewModel ` class details as well.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Please see updated question

Comment: When you debug your Create method, does timePeriodVM.TimePeriod.TotalAvgHours have the expected value? If it has, do you really update the database (you don't show that code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to disable attribute property applied on you are textbox you are not able to fetch data of it on post instead of it use readonly attribute property on textbox.

Try :

```
 @Html.TextBox("TotalAvgHours", "", "{0:c}", new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control", id = "res2" })
```